# Push notification click opens the latest article, not the relevant one

Tags: android, push-notification

I am working on an app where i am using custom Push Notification whenever there is an update from server that we need to send the notification, i am sending the notification using Notification builder and everything is working as expected, and i am redirecting the user to the relevant post on the ViewPager by mapping the Heading of the Notification.

I am attaching the code i am using

**Notification Builder code**

```
Intent resultIntentArticle = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
resultIntentArticle.putExtra("pushNotificationClick", "yes");
resultIntentArticle.putExtra("heading", allArticles.get(0).getArticleHeading().trim());
resultIntentArticle.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
        0, resultIntentArticle,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_not);
} else {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_not);
}
mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
mBuilder.setContentTitle("" + allArticles.get(0).getArticleHeading().trim())
        .setContentText("" + allArticles.get(0).getArticleContent().trim())
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
assert mNotificationManager != null;
mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* Request Code */, mBuilder.build());
currentNotificationStatus = "sent";
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("currentNotificationStatus" +
        "", "" + currentNotificationStatus).apply();
```

I am sending two variables with PendingIntent i.e. **pushNotificationClick** and **heading** and am recieving it inside my Activity like this.

```
notificationClickedStatus = getIntent().getStringExtra("pushNotificationClick");
notificationHeading = getIntent().getStringExtra("heading");
```

Now the problem is that whenever we get 2-3 notifications and the user clicked on the very first notification that i have got, i am still getting the latest Notification heading in my activity. Earlier it was working completely fine, but now i am not getting any clue.

Comment: won't `allArticles.get(0).getArticleHeading()` always return heading for the very first article?

Comment: @farhanjk Everytime i am building a notification, the value of allArticles.get(0).getArticleHeading() is different